# How to handle tables using selenium

Tags: selenium

I got confused while handling the tables
1.How to click on the check boxes in the table
2.How to click on the values in the table
3.How to handle dynamic and static tables
4.How to count the number of rows and columns available in the table

[image]

Comment: Please share what you tried ?

Comment: a screenshot of the same, with relevant HTML code would be helpful

Comment: Actually I tried to select the 1st row and 2nd column value.but i want to know about two scenarios 1.May the value of mentioned cell will change in future at the time how i can select the specified cell from the table?  2.If I want to select the specified value how I can do it? I have attached the image above

Answer (score 0):

1. How to handle dynamic and static web tables.

inspect the elements in your table randomly and copy there XPATH for eg i am taking 2 xpath of 2 elements in one column but in two rows

1. `[@id='hello']/tbody/tr[**2**]/td`
2. `[@id='hello']/tody/tr[**3**]/td`

here 2 and 3 are changing rest is same you have to divide your x path in 2 parts

```
String beforeXpath="[@id='hello']/tbody/tr[";
String afterXpath="]/td";
```

then use for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=here you can get size of rows using tag name;i++)
{
// with this you can click on any element or text 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforeXpath+i+afterXpath)).click(); 
}
```

how to get row count:-

```
List<WebElement>list=driver.findElements(By.TagName("tr"));
System.out.println(list.getsize());
```

how to get column count:-

```
List<WebElement>list1=driver.findElements(By.TagName("td"));
System.out.println(list1.getsize());
```

Answer (score 0):

The most generic way is to use `tagName` method with values as `tr` and `td`.

```
@Test 
public void testWebTable()  { 
    WebElement simpleTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[2]")); 

    // Get all rows 
    List<WebElement> rows = simpleTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

    // rows count assert and count 
    Assert.assertEquals(rows.size(),4); 
    System.out.println("Total Rows count in table" + rows.size());

    // Print data from each row 
    for (WebElement row : rows) { 
        List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

        // column count assert and count
        Assert.assertEquals(cols.size(),4); 
        System.out.println("Total Column count in each row" + cols.size());

        for (WebElement col : cols) {
            // to select specific column compare its text
             if (col.getText().equals("some text")) {
              col.click(); // assuming td contains check box or link
              col.sendKeys(); // assuming td contains text box
              }
            // print complete table data                 
             System.out.print(col.getText() + "\t"); 

           } System.out.println(); 
       }
    }
```

Also to click you have to use `WebElement` in second for loop for clicking.
To handle dynamic tables you have to use xpath axis strategy to locate elements
e.g. write xpath till static column which is not changed and then use xpath axis methods like preceding,following,following sibling etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the above code but it's printing the all table values from the table

Comment: Actually,1.I want to know the count of rows,columns size and it also showing the content of current tab only i.e if 200 records available in first tab we can able to see only 50 records so it's printing only that 50 records

Comment: @YaswanthG
`rows.size()` - will give row count as shown in code, u can print it
`col.size()` - will give col count as shown in code, u can print it
 Only visible table rows and columns will be printed. Make sure this in code above `simpleTable`  this webelement locator should be correct.
I have also updated code for better understanding.